# Trigger Issue with Azure pipelines via UI

Tags: azure-devops

We have a YML Azure release pipeline per below which we are trying to get triggered when our build pipeline is completed.

We noticed that the release YML is not getting triggered when the Build pipeline is partially successful. Although when we use the trigger part in release pipeline per below snippet then it gets triggered even when build is partially successful but when we are configuring the trigger via UI per attached screenshot then it is NOT getting triggered on partial success of Build pipeline .

Below is when we did trigger setting in YML code itself -- this works even with partial successful build.
[image]

Below is when we did trigger setting in UI only -- this DOES NOT work in case of partial successful build.
[image]

Please let us know what should we do to get the release pipeline triggered even when the Build is partially successful in case of when we are setting the trigger via UI.

Thanks
Sharad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with Cece.

As a workaround, we could add task power shell and call the API [Queue build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to trigger the build.

Steps:

Create PAT token->save it in the build pipeline variable and save it **secret**.

Add task power shell and set the condition to `Even if a previous task has failed, even if the build was canceled`

[image]

Power shell script:

```
$token = "$(pat)"
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{project name}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.1-preview.6"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))


$JSON = @"
{
  "definition": {
    "id": {Build definition ID}
  }
}
"@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -ContentType application/json -body $JSON
write-host $response
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check the documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

> Previously, you may have navigated to the classic editor for your YAML
> pipeline and configured **build completion triggers** in the UI. While
> that model still works, it is no longer recommended. The recommended
> approach is to specify **pipeline triggers** directly within the YAML
> file. Build completion triggers as defined in the classic editor have
> various drawbacks, which have now been addressed in pipeline triggers.

Comment: i can NOT use pipeline triggers in yml because i can NOT fix the build pipeline name in source.. thats why for each pipeline i was trying to choose UI triggers as mentioned in documentation but that is not supporting partial completed Builds.

Comment: Could you elaborate "NOT fix the build pipeline name"? How about the workaround Vito provided below?

Comment: That means i can not actually hard code the build pipeline name in yml. Thats why wanted to use the trigger from UI but thats not working in case of partial successful builds.

Comment: I'm sorry for this limitation. Are you able to edit the build pipeline? If you can edit build pipeline, you may try @Vito's workaround that use rest api in build pipeline to trigger release pipeline.

Comment: Cece, could you please suggest if we can use variable at the build pipeline name while configuring pipeline resource.. i was unable to use a variable at that level and thats why was going with approach of setting trigger using UI.

Comment: I'm afraid `resources` doesn't accept variable, here is already a similar user voice: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/816606/allow-variables-at-resourcesrepositoriesrepository.html. In addition, check the NOTE in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#macro-syntax-variables): Variables are only expanded for `stages`, `jobs`, and `steps`. You cannot, for example, use macro syntax inside a `resource` or `trigger`.

Comment: Does my reply help you?